# compiler throwing error when trying to any dependencies in a maven project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Fair amount of experience with java but have only made console applications without using any dependencies. I am currently trying to make a rest api to handle request for my web application. I am using Apache Maven 3.6.3 and have the dependencies in my pom.xml file.

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When I try to compile my project I get the same error for each of my dependencies (listing the error for the http client)
`error: package org.apache.http.client.methods does not exist`

Comment: There are many variations of http clients, and it is now even part of java SE. So java version is of interest, and often the IDE can search for a maven dependency to have some class. Also Ctrl+Space in the version field can give the latest version, 5.0 something I remember. _Not the nicest part of getting the libraries right._

Comment: Please show the code which fails to compile and the full error message. Also show how you compile your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is connected with some dependencies which use an old version of this library. A possible solution is to add in the pom file the dependency in the **dependencyManagement**, this is a way to override all the possible imports of the library.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
         </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```